# Order query by timestamptz

Tags: postgresql, sql-order-by

Trying to sort the result of a query by timestamptz column 'sent' (oldest to be displayed first on the page). I've tried order by sent ASC and by DESC but it seems to bring them back the same (incorrect) order.

This is the query -

```
SELECT messages.bootcamper_id, first_name,
    surname,
    photo_url,
    message,
    sent
FROM messages  
  LEFT JOIN bootcampers ON messages.bootcamper_id = bootcampers.bootcamper_id 
ORDER BY sent DESC 
LIMIT 30;
```

Here is the create table script for the table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS messages (
  message_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, 
  sent timestamptz NOT NULL DEFAULT now(), 
  bootcamper_id INTEGER REFERENCES bootcampers(bootcamper_id), 
  message TEXT
)
```

Here's a screenshot of the table in pgadmin

[image]

Comment: The screenshot looks properly sorted ASC - is that the output of the `order by DESC`?. Is it possible that pgAdmin sorts the rows on the client (e.g. based by message_id)?

Comment: Yeah it is properly sorted in the screenshot. I'm not sure about pgAdmin, but the messages are printed the wrong way on the front end no matter whether i have ASC or DESC

Comment: Any idea anyone?